# How much memory did the Opportunity rover have (in bytes)?

Tags: mars, opportunity

How many GB/TB of memory did Opportunity have in total? How much of it was used during the mission?

Comment: There's no need to shout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Mars Exploration Rover avionics page](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/technology/avionics/) says

> Onboard memory includes 128 megabytes of random access memory, augmented by 256 megabytes of flash memory and smaller amounts of other non-volatile memory, which allows the system to retain data even without power.

My suspicion is that all of it was used at some time or other, though I'm having difficulty finding any precise citations for that at the moment because they get drowned out by all the articles written about the Flash problem.  [A blog post from Ontrack](https://www.ontrack.com/en-us/blog/how-to-store-data-on-mars) mentions that Curiosity's memory allocator "has its own diagnostics function, which generates a map of all memory usage;" I believe I have read that the MER software also had that feature (but again, no luck with a citation yet).  The amount of dynamically allocated memory was apparently pretty small, though:  [Overview of the Mars Exploration Rovers’ Autonomous Mobility and Vision Capabilities](https://robotics.jpl.nasa.gov/media/documents/mer_autonomy_icra_2007.pdf) (Maimone, Leger and Biesiadecki) mentions

> Dynamic memory allocation is strongly discouraged by the coding standards document, but some non-system RAM is available in a set of dedicated memory pools of 4 Mbytes, 9 Mbytes, and up to 10 additional 2 Mbyte blocks (use of these 2 Mbyte blocks reduces the memory available for image processing and is also discouraged).

Those few megabytes seem like the best candidates for possibly not being used at a particular time during MER operations.